# I want to use a modal to send mail, via a php file and I want the pop closed once submit is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form that loads nicely via bootstrap modal once the page loads. I want to process and send the once I click submit and the modal should close immediately without refreshing the page. Below are my codes. It is not working. Please I need help. With a php file it sends the mail but it takes me to the php file and gets stuck there. I believe it's a small thing but I can't wrap my head around it.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#Modal').modal('show');

  });

   $('#btn_send').click(function(){
      var name  = $(":input[name='name']").val();
      var email = $(":input[name='email']").val();

      var varData = 'name=' + name + '&email=' +email; 

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: varData,
        success: function(){
            alert('Mail sent. Thank you.');
        }
    });
});
});
```

```css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="form_pp">
  <div id="Modal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-header" style="margin-top:120px;">
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="YOUR FULL NAME" name="name" type="text" required autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" name="email" type="email" required>
            </div>

            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#c13b01" id="btn_send">SEND</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#c13b01" name="send" id="btn_cancel" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
php file
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST('email))) {
 $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
     $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
     $subject = "Results from Online contact form:\n\n";

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'mail@mail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email. "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject;

     @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

}
```

Comment: use the bootstrap modal option `$('#mymodal').modal('hide'); ` place it at success function

Comment: @Leandro Ruel Like this? if yes, it isn't working **bold** $(function() {
   $(window).load(function() {
     $('#Modal').modal('show');
 
   });
 
   $("#btn_send").click(function() {
     var name = $("name").val();
     var email = $("recipientmail@mail.com").val();
     var data = {
       name: name,
       email: email
     };
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "index.php",
       data: data,
       success: function() {
       $('#Modal').modal('hide');
         $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
       }
     });
   });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of @Eric Dohmen, I figured I missed out quotes and the correct block parenthesis for the email variable. Here it is:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
 $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
     $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
     $subject = "Results from Online contact form:\n\n";

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'mail@mail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email. "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

}
else{
    echo alert('Message did not send');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leandro's answer is part of your success. I would say that the reason the php script isn't working, is because it doens't get any data submited and therefor can't send an email

In order to retrieve the data from both the name as well as the email you need to change the part where it says

```
var name = $("name").val();
var email = $("recipientmail@mail.com").val();
```

to

```
var name  = $(":input[name='name']").val();
var email = $(":input[name='email']").val();
```

That should help you to get your data over to the server.

Comment: @Eric Dohmen thank you. But the mail is not sending. It only acts like it gets processed. I want to mention that I have an external php file that is index.php, that does the processing.

Comment: debug that. look if it is sending the data or not.

Comment: This line of code is a tick missing:
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST('email))) {
You need an extra tick ' after the $_POST['email'] as well as that it should be blockquotes for the email part just like you use at the name post variable

Comment: @Erik Dohmen, thanks for pointing that out. I also realised I used ('email') instead of ['email']. Everything is now fine.